# Compiling WindowsRegistry for lua on windows

Tags: lua

i am trying to use the library http://lua-users.org/wiki/WindowsRegistry for accessing the windows registry from lua. since there is only the source code provided, i must first compile it. i can't figure out how to compile it on windows. I've tried using GCC, without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As moteus observes, winapi can access the registry, among other useful things.

https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi

There are .bat files for building with mingw and MVSC - look at the link in the summary for the online documentation.